# Automatization of file movement with a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, automation, file-rename, file-move

I would like to make a simple bash script where the goal is to make it run another script and move the output files from that script to a different folder.

The problem is , that this `somescript.pl` creates a file like this:
`customfile-Withcontent-202305231159.tar.gz`

As you can see there is a fixated prefix `customfile-Withcontent-` but there is a suffix for the name with the actual date.

What I would like to achieve is to make a bash script, which some kind of autocompletes the actually created file, and moves it to the desired folder, somehow like this:

For example:

```
./somescript.py  #this script creates a file #first I create the file
mv customfile-Withcontent *pressing TAB or smth* so it completes the filename /Desiredfolder/Desiredfilename.tar.gz #moves the file with renaming.
```

The `somescript.py` is not editable, anyone has any suggestions?

I tried to edit the `somescript.py` but it made wrong everything, and it doesnt run so I think that wouldnt work. I would like to automate a work, there are 200 files to move.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO). [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: To me it is not fully clear what you want to achieve. Please [edit] your question and add more details. Do you want to move/rename about 200 existing files `customfile-Withcontent-202305231159.tar.gz` once? Do you want to rename every file just after it has been created by `somescript.py`? How do you determine the destination directory and file name for every existing file? Show an example of a few input files and the expected result. Can you show the contents of `somescript.py` and what you tried to change?

Comment: When you talk about "pressing tab", that sounds like you're looking for an interactive process. We don't do that here -- our focus is on scripting. But if there's only one match, you can just use a glob or wildcard to find it. (If there's more than one match, you need to decide how you want the code to pick a specific one to use).

Comment: Essentially, though, what you're looking for is the same whether it's files or directories. I'm closing with a file-centric duplicate, but the same technique will work for a directory name. (That said, don't use any answer that tells you to run `ls -t` -- those answers are all buggy for the reasons given in [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); use the techniques given in [BashFAQ #3](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) instead)

Comment: `mv customfile-Withcontent* /Desiredfolder/Desiredname.tar.gz`